# Connecting two numpy array channels

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, for example:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]]
```

Which are channels of the same image. I would like to get the "connected" channels array in a as pythonic way as possible. wanted outcome:

```
c = [[[1,11],[2,12],[3,13]],
    [[4,14],[5,15],[6,16]],
    [[7,17],[8,18],[9,19]]]
```

**What Iv'e tried:**
I created an array of the same size and looped over both the source array to connect them.

```
for x in range(len(a)):
    for y in range(len(a[x])):
        c[x][y] = [a[x][y],b[x][y]]
```

**What I need:** I would love to find a more efficient, modular and pythonic way of implementing this.

Comment: How do you initialize `c` in the last snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.stack` on the second axis:

```
>>> np.stack((a,b),axis=2)
array([[[ 1, 11],
        [ 2, 12],
        [ 3, 13]],

       [[ 4, 14],
        [ 5, 15],
        [ 6, 16]],

       [[ 7, 17],
        [ 8, 18],
        [ 9, 19]]])
```

Checking that it's the same as your `c` array:

```
c = np.array([[[1,11],[2,12],[3,13]],
              [[4,14],[5,15],[6,16]],
              [[7,17],[8,18],[9,19]]])

>>> (c == np.stack((a,b),axis=2)).all()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [`dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html).  You mention this is an image, and from the docs:

> This is a simple way to stack 2D arrays (images) into a single 3D array for processing.

```
np.dstack((a, b))
```

```
array([[[ 1, 11],
        [ 2, 12],
        [ 3, 13]],

       [[ 4, 14],
        [ 5, 15],
        [ 6, 16]],

       [[ 7, 17],
        [ 8, 18],
        [ 9, 19]]])
```

Minor note, the docs also state that `concatenate`, and `stack` should be preferred, as they are more general.